# Origin of the phrase 'ducking & diving'

Tags: expressions

'The Dog and Duck' is not an uncommon pub name in England.I have read in The Dictionary of Pub Names (Wordsworth Reference Series) that the pub name sometimes originated from the sport of duck hunting. This was favoured by Charles 2nd and remained popular until the early 19th century. Ducks wings were pinioned and they were thrown into the village pond to be hunted by spaniels. The only way the ducks could escape was to dive. I have read a number of explanations of the usage of the phrase, but could this have been the origin?

Comment: In ordinary duck hunting (the kind where your goal is a dead duck to eat for dinner), after you shoot the duck, your retriever swims out into the lake and brings it back to you. (Why do you think they're called *retrievers*?) This "sport" you're describing seems like it originated with the process of training retrievers. Anyway, I don't see why "The Dog and Duck" couldn't refer to the regular sport of duck-hunting rather than this dog-training version.

Comment: And, rather off-topic, these spaniels were probably the extinct [English Water Spaniels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Water_Spaniel), rather than the kind we're more used to nowadays.

Comment: The term 'Dog and Duck' is indeed the name of many pubs.But for some reason, above all other pub names it has come to symbolise British rural parochialism. Certain tabloid newspapers are said to be addressed to the people in 'the Dog and Duck'. It has replaced the 'Clapham Omnibus' as a reference point for ordinary humankind.

Answer (score 2):

Ducking and diving are, like dodging, evasive maneuvers, and it is a happy coincidence that the three words are pleasantly alliterative. I see no compelling reason to assume that the alliterative connection alone isn't sufficient reason for the two words to appear together in an expression, however. The fact that ducks dive may add graphical embellishment to the phrase, but it is probably only incidental to the existence of the phrase, and not causal.

The "Dog and Duck" expression is a typical English pub name because they are two related tokens of country life, the words are short and are graphically compatible (look good together on a sign). This practice is - or was - a cultural phenomenon. The alliteration adds value, but in this case is somewhat incidental: "Pig and Fiddle" is another typical name for a pub; it isn't alliterative but it sounds fun, and commands a good image.